# Java: (File) Scanner's first "next" adds an unknown symbol

Tags: java, file, utf-8

I am working with a `Scanner` that scans a file for specific data in Java.

The first result it gets (as the first word in a text file) should be something like `test`, but, it returns this word with the *unknown* character at the front of the word. (By that, I mean the square that appears if a character is unknown, or if it is not supported in a font, like this: ☐).
The text file I am working with is encoded in UTF-8.

This is the situation:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("data/File.txt"));
[...]
scanner.next();
scanner.close();
```

So, what it returns is `☐test`, where there should be `test`. Of course, the original text file features a `test` without such a weird sign.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: With what encoding does your code read the file?

Comment: Well, I'm just using `new Scanner(file)`, I'm not specifying that.

Comment: That means it's using [the platform's default charset.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html#defaultCharset%28%29) What is it? What do you get if you explicitly specify UTF-8, as in `new Scanner(someFile, "UTF-8")`?

Comment: I'm getting still the same thing.

Comment: Instead of using a scanner, can you get the char code of the first character in the file? Perhaps the file itself has ...whatever that character is... and it's your text editor that's "lying" to you, not your code.

Comment: Open your text file in a hex editor. Are you sure it contains what you think it does?

Comment: If I'm reading the first char, it gives me a line seperator.

Comment: Sounds like you've found your problem. It's not the code. It's the data.

Comment: @lukulus Do you know what a text editor is? Use it.

Comment: @lukulus how you are creating your `File.txt` file? did you used `writeChars` method

Comment: No, it was created manually with the Windows Editor. There was a bit UTF-8 to ANS and back conversion included, however.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that weird character as an output to console because console is not encoded to UTF-8.

Change the console from `Run Configuration` -> `Common` to display UTF-8 Content

[image]